# How to implement Netty-SocketIO

Tags: tomcat, websocket, socket.io, netty, atmosphere

I am planning to use a **SocketIO - Netty** framework in my already existing java project. Right now I am implementing this project on a Tomcat 6 server.

So to make the above mentioned changes do I need a change of server ? I am little confused here. Can we implement SocketIO-Netty framework on Tomcat6 or is it only possible with Netty server?

If so I have read somewhere that we can use another framework called Atmosphere with Netty(**NettoSphere**) so that we can implement it on Tomcat. But again I have read articles saying that WebSockets can be implemented on Tomcat 7.0.27 or above. But I am not sure on whether SocketIO can be implemented on Tomcat 6. Some clarification on this is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's as easy as pie, just create `com.corundumstudio.socketio.SocketIOServer`. Example:

In your tomcat Servlet.init method type follow:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.setHostname("localhost");
config.setPort(81);

SocketIOServer server = new SocketIOServer(config);
server.start();
```